# json parsing in javascript with find length and switch with index value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
"slider":
[{
    "album":{
        "name":"album 0",
        "title":"title 0",
        "description":"desc 0"
    },
    "album":{
        "name":"album 1",
        "title":"title 1",
        "description":"desc 1"
    },
    "album":{
        "name":"album 2",
        "title":"title 2",
        "description":"desc 2"
    }
  }]
}
```

I want to find the length of the albums and I wanted to switch to the album with index value.

please help me...

Comment: this is not valid `JSON`: your nested object has the same key `album` repeated more than once. May you consider to slightly change this structure?

Comment: you don't need to parse json in javascript. the reason why it's called **J**ava**S**cript**O**bject**N**otation is that json is valid javascript so you can use it as any other object (potentially after evaluating it if it's passed as a string to you)

Comment: @RuneFS: When a JSON encoded string is passed too you, you damn well parse it before using it, and _never_ __Ever__ `eval`-uate it. _EVAL IS EVIL_, just use `JSON.parse(JSONstring);`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem as such I agree but JSON.parse is a really bad name for a method that evaluates :) after all it's an method that returns an object value and not an AST. but my point was to use ready-made functionality and just use the result as any other object

Comment: @RuneFS: Fair enough, `JSON.parse` did use `eval` back in the days... _but not without sanitizing_. Nowadays `JSON` is natively supported, though. I fear I misread your comment, I thought you meant _use `eval` if the data is passed as a string_, but I take it you meant: _evaluate if it's a string, and process it if needed_

Answer (score 1):

If you have

```
var slider= {
  "albums": [ 
    {
        "name":"album 0",
        "title":"title 0",
        "description":"desc 0"
    },
    {   "name":"album 1",
        "title":"title 1",
        "description":"desc 1"
    },
    {
        "name":"album 2",
        "title":"title 2",
        "description":"desc 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

then slider.albums[1].name will give you "album 1"

---

**UPDATE**
So in a for loop:

```
var albums = slider.albums;
for (var i=0,n=albums.length, album;i<n;i++) { 
  album = albums[i];
  alert((i+1)+":"+album.name+" - " + album.title);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/S4TTx/)

Comment: This seems like a proper answer for the need above. =)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, It actually solve problem.can you please help me how to give reference variable or object to this json data, as i wanted to use this data on other function too.

Answer (score 0):

I would go about picking a structure rather like:

```
"slider":[
    {
        "name":"album 0",
        "title":"title 0",
        "description":"desc 0"
    },
    {
        "name":"album 1",
        "title":"title 1",
        "description":"desc 1"
    },
    {
        "name":"album 2",
        "title":"title 2",
        "description":"desc 2"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are modeling your JSON is incorrect.  Currently you have 3 keys that all have the same identifier (album).  You should instead change that into an array.

Here's a good example on how to do this:

```
var slider = {
    "albums":
    [
        {
            "name":"album 0",
            "title":"title 0",
            "description":"desc 0"
        },
        {
            "name":"album 1",
            "title":"title 1",
            "description":"desc 1"
        },
        {
            "name":"album 2",
            "title":"title 2",
            "description":"desc 2"
        }
    ]
}

slider.albums.length
```